# If $\lim_{n \to \infty }b_n=L$, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

True/False: If there exists $L \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty }b_n=L$, and we know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent, then  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$ is convergent.

If $a_n,b_n \ge 0$ then this is true from the limit definition.

But what happens if $a_n,b_n$ are not necessarily non-negative?

Thanks!

Comment: $a_n=b_n=\frac {(-1)^{n}} {\sqrt n}$

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!